# MVC Session not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am trying to make a shoppingcart in a MVC project with the session storage but the Session variable isnt working. It doesn't show the session as intellisense either.

[image]

Maybe the "Session" variable is removed or change name in MVC CORE? I have been stuck all day with this problem and cant really find anything related to the problem.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current contex"

Comment: Do you have `app.UseSession();` before `app.UseMvc` in your configuration? Have you tried getting to Session via `HttpContext.Session`? Did you google "session asp.net mvc core" to see what others are doing?

Comment: Sadly didnt work but just to be sure by configurations do you mean the startup file? where the " app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>..." is?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did it find HttpContext?

Comment: I think i got it now with the combination of you guys comments thanks! it's one of my first projects and i try to follow guides but that dosnt work that well when wverything i find is from 2013 and earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get Session from the injected `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation.

So in your class

```
private ISession _session;
public MyClassName(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) //constructor
{
   this._session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
}
```

Now in your Action  method you can use the Set method.

```
public IActionResult OrderNow()
{
    _session.Set("myKey",myObjectByteArray);
    //to do : return something
}
```

Assuming you have the [initial setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#installing-and-configuring-session) done for enabling session in your app

I also recommend you reading this excellent post about session

[Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)